# apache2 server-status page using mod_perl and no apache workers

Tags: apache, perl, apache2, mod-perl

Is there a way to access the server-status page located at http://localhost/server-status without using any apache2 workers?

This is needed because if all workers are busy, and apache2 is frozen, it is impossible to get the information to use it for debugging or monitoring.

Comment: Well, at face value, the answer is obviously no. You can't make a request to the web server when the server has no workers. You said so yourself. So the real question is whether you can set a worker aside for this one page, or if you can get mod_status (the provided of `/server-status`) to log the information somewhere outside of apache.

Comment: I don't know if the former is possible, and nothing in [the documentation for mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) suggests the latter is possible. However, you could write a script that periodically requests `/server-status` and writes it to disk. The request will fail when the server is *fully* busy, but the server status right before it became fully busy will probably be useful too

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/647391/apache2-status-when-server-overloaded/648385#648385

Comment: I am unable to find a working version of mod_backdoor. An ideal solution would be to reserve an apache fork to only handle requests on localhost/server-status